# Why does JQM show user dialog during page transition?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

When I tap a link button in my JQM(JQuery Mobile) application that changes to another page for some reason I am seeing a flash of a user dialog. Nothing I have set up so far would in clude this in a transition, however is one link that would cause this to pop-up, *this is not being clicked at all.

```
<p><b>Marketing Rep</b>         <span class="tdright"><a data-bind="text: CreatorName" id="A1" data-rel="dialog" href="#UserDialog" ></a></span></p>
```

The dialog itself is populated via KnockoutJS.

```
<div data-role="dialoge" id="UserDialog" > 
<div data-role="content">
<table style=" background-color:White; width: 100%;">
   <tr ><td></td><td><a style="float:right" href="#" onclick="CloseDialog()"  data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-corners="true" 
              data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-theme="a"/>                                         </td></tr>
   <tr><td class="tdleft">Name:      </td><td class="tdright" data-bind="text:CreatorName">        </td></tr>
   <tr><td class="tdleft">Telephone: </td><td class="tdright" data-bind="text:CreatorTelephone">   </td></tr>
   <tr><td class="tdleft">Mobile:    </td><td class="tdright" data-bind="text:CreatorMobile">      </td></tr>
   <tr><td class="tdleft">Email:     </td><td class="tdright" data-bind="text:CreatorEmail">       </td></tr>                               
   <tr>
    <td> 
        <a id="TelephoneLink">
            <img alt="phone icon" src="../../Content/img/telephone-icon.png" />
        </a>
        <a id="MailToLink">
            <img alt="email icon" src="../../Content/img/emailicon.png" />
        </a> 
    </td>
   </tr>

     <tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of the cause, though it seems to be a known issue in JQM, but I fixed it by using

```
transition="slide"
```

instead of leaving it at the default transition.